# Adding margin to parameter - Syntax Help - Jquery / Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to add a `-53px margin` to the `toggleClass` parameters but I'm unsure how to write the correct syntax.

The code below is what I have and it's working great; It triggers when my `div` reaches the top of the page but I need to to work `53px` sooner. I tried using `.offset()` for a solution but couldn't get anything to work.

```
var targetScroll = $('.contentwrapper').position().top,
currentScroll = $('html').scrollTop() || $('body').scrollTop();
styledDiv.toggleClass('fixedPos', currentScroll >= targetScroll);
```

Any advice and suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why do you need a -53px margin? What are you trying to do? Could you please build a fiddle or codepen?

Comment: And how much sooner is 'sooner'? You could use `document.onReady` :P

Comment: Not sure `document.onReady` exists.

Comment: I'll start working on a fiddle. I was hoping there was an easy was to write that into the logic:

styledDiv.toggleClass('fixedPos', currentScroll >= targetScroll -53px);

or 

var targetScroll = $('.contentwrapper').position().top -53px,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try

`styledDiv.toggleClass('fixedPos', currentScroll + 53 >= (targetScroll));`

As currentScroll and targetScroll will be scalars not px amounts

Comment: Thanks DGS for the answer! I ended up adding the +53 to the currentScroll instead of the targetScroll and it worked out great. Thanks!